# Does this system of Diophantine equations have a solution?

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

> Are there natural numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ such that we have $a \neq b$ and $a \neq c$ and $b \neq c$ and that they are solution of this system of equations:
>
> $9ab-3a-3b+1=d^2$
>
> $9ac-3a-3c+1=e^2$
>
> $9bc-3b-3c+1=f^2$

Comment: By the way, you have more than 80 questions, most of which have answers -- yet you've clicked the accept button only for a fraction of that. Maybe you could start reviewing some of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many. Let,

$$a = (2p+1)^2+2p^2\\
b = (2q+1)^2+2q^2\\
c = (2r+1)^2+2r^2$$

then,

$$d =4(3p+1)^2(3q+1)^2\\
e =4(3p+1)^2(3r+1)^2\\
f =4(3q+1)^2(3r+1)^2$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you came up with the expressions for a,b and c?

Comment: @user115962: Just by looking at solutions $a<b<c$ generated by _Mathematica_ and some intuition.

Comment: @user115962 It accords to my solution for $t=1, x=3p+1, y=3q+1, z=3r+1.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let $3a-1,3b-1,3c-1$ be $2^3,2^5,2^7$.

Comment: $t=1, x=2, y=4, z=8.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, infinitely many.
All the solutions can be obtained from the conditions
$$\begin{cases}
3a-1=(3t-1)x^2\\
3b-1=(3t-1)y^2\\
3c-1=(3t-1)z^2\\
3\not|\ xyz,\\
x,y,z,t\in\mathbb Z
\end{cases}$$